# Cannot find main javascript in electron using require

Tags: javascript, electron

I have the following `electron` project structure:

```
Project/
|__main.js
|__app
    |___ js
         |__ login.js
```

In `login.js` file I need to import `main.js`:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
const main = remote.require('../../main.js')
```

The problem is that the above import doesn't work. I tried multiple ways and combinations of `path`.

Moving the `login.js` file in the root directory near `main.js` and using the path `./main.js` works how is supposed to. However, I don't quite want to make this, I want to keep a good structure of my project.

The error I get in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../main.js'
Error: Cannot find module '../../main.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\Users\Marian Pavel\Documents\GitHub\Project\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marian Pavel\Documents\GitHub\Project\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\rpc-server.js:232:70)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marian Pavel\Documents\GitHub\Project\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\dist\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\web-contents.js:219:13)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

Any idea how can I debug this problem or solve it ? I'm out of ideas :(

Best,
Marian

Comment: What error you receive in your console?

Comment: @DavidR edited with the log

Comment: What happens when you change your `const main` statement to `const main = require('../../main.js');` (I don't think `remote` is needed there)

Comment: after changing this I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined  in  app.on('ready', () => {

Comment: Which means that you had overcame the previous error and the `main.js` is being read now. Can you please post the a screenshot of the present error which you are receiving?

Comment: I am wondering why you are requiring `main.js`. That's for bootstrapping the electron framework and your application. I don't think your code should depend on it.

Comment: Kinda solved all the errors, I don't understand why remote is needed or not. main.js is my main javascript files where I define the window and it's properties.